# How to style text using character as separated with jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I'm stuck on a request from a client. They are uploading blocks of text using line breaks instead of list items or paragraphs. Then, on each line, they have a few words followed by a colon, followed by a description.

For example: Frame Type: blah blah blah

They would like the text following the colon to align to the right of the div. If there were paragraphs or li's, I would use each(), but that doesn't work with simply text and line breaks.

I've started a fiddle, which doesn't work, but I think is on the right track.

```
$('.techspecdescription').each(function() {
var str = $(this).html();
var index = str.indexOf(":");
var title = str.substr(0, index);
var value = str.substr(index, str.length - 1);
$(this).html("<span style=\"background-color: yellow\">" + title + "</span>" + value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ye79c8eo/

Thanks for you help.

Comment: That fiddle isn't working, says it can't find $.  Try fixing that.  I'm sure you can come up with a solution to this.  I'll give it a try if I can get the fiddle to use $.

Comment: Yeah the fiddle doesn't work... I'm stuck. Here is a version with list items, but like I said, I'm working with plain text https://jsfiddle.net/441yexoy/

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this answers your Question**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/441yexoy/1/)

### Code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="techspecdescription">
<li>First: value1</li>
<li>Second: value2</li>
<li>Third: value3</li>
</div>
</div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>
$(function () {

$('.techspecdescription li').each(function() { 
var str = $(this).html();
var index = str.indexOf(":");
var title = str.substr(0, index);
var value = str.substr(index, str.length - 1);
$(this).html("<span style='background-color: yellow'>"+title+"</span><span style=\"float:right;\">" + value + "</span>"  );
});            
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye79c8eo/12/)**

First, you should split your lines by `<br>` tag:

```
$('.techspecdescription').html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/);
```

Then optional trim each line, remove empty lines and iterate through it and parse as you need:

```
var container = $('.techspecdescription');

// split text to lines by <br> / <br/> tag
var lines = container.html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/);

// trim each line
lines = $.map(lines, $.trim);
// remove empty lines
lines = lines.filter(function(line) {
    return line !== ''
});

var newHtml = '';

lines.forEach(function(line) {
    // split & trim
    var values = $.map(line.split(':'), $.trim);

  newHtml += '<span class="title">'+ values[0] +': </span><span class="value">'+ values[1] +'</span><br>';
});

container.html(newHtml);
```

Comment: thanks Martin... that works. I updated your fiddle and added bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/Lej5c4sk/

Comment: Getting a console error... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined   var lines = container.html().split(/<br\s*\/?>/);

Comment: A can't see any console error :) Not even in yours fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Martins answer works, you could also try this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6ufccdun/3/)

```
var $desc = $( ".techspecdescription" )
.contents()
.filter(function() {return this.nodeType === 3;})
.replaceWith( function(){
var vals = $(this).text().split(':');
return "<p><b>"+vals[0]+"</b><em>"+vals[1]+"</em></p>";
} )
.end()
.filter( "br" )
.remove();
```